# Magmi Import 'price' Update Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, price, magmi

So, after doing a Magmi Import to a product with 'price' included, whilst looking through the product catalog in the back-end of Magento, it will appear as if the product hasn't been changed (price stays as old price) along with looking at the product in a category view in front-end.

However, if going into the actual product editor in the back-end, OR going to the actual product page in front-end, it shows the proper updated price. Also, if you now save the product in back-end, it will save the new price to where it can be seen everywhere properly.

Any idea why this happens and how it can be done to import the new price and have it working in all areas?

MAGmi: v0.7.22 //
Magento: CE1.9.3.2

**UPDATE:**

I have done the re-indexing and cleared cache many a time, this is actually a recurring issue that I've had for a while, just now taking the opportunity to try and resolve it rather than manually fix.

Comment: I'm having the same issues. Tried store view, ect. My Brain hurts. Re indexed. Cleared Cache. Still nothing. Just went down to one sku to test. Below is my report and the CSV used. I've also tried with store just "admin" with same reuslts no updates. store,sku,Price,Force FS,Ship Cost,package_id "admin,storeview1,storeview2,storeview3",TP-87740,384.99,399.99,15, title:MAGMI by dweeves - version:0.7.18
startup:Running Magmi Product Import Engine v1.7.1 by dweeves
startup:Import Profile:Prices
startup:Import Mode:update
step:step:0.5%
plugin;Magmi_CSVDataSource;pluginhello:CSV Datasource-1.3-Dwe

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144588)

Answer (score 2):

**Try these below, might be it's help for you.**

***Solution 1 :-***

> Have you performed a Re-Index after import?(Or have "Magmi Magento Reindexer" Plugin enabled on import)
> That should fix the issue and show updated price also in frontend category view
>
> Re-Indexed only product prices index?
>
> Probably also re-index for product flat data index is required for update price everywhere.
> Or go for a full re-index (which is what Magmi reindexer would do) to verify its indeed an issue with indexes and not related to something else (e. g. some cache, FPC etc.)

***Solution 2:-***

> To work with multistore, you MUST vary on "store" column putting
> storeviews code, not on "websites" column.
>
> here:
>
> store, sku,  price
>
> abc, 1001, 5.00
>
> bab, 1001, 7.00
>
> should do it.

Comment: How can i import images for my multi store.multi store details : https://snag.gy/rGlAPY.jpg and csv screen shots : https://snag.gy/Q9ZEme.jpg. its not working. may i know what is an error?

Answer (score 0):

Once you upload prices go to `System > Index Management` and reindex:

1. Product prices
2. Product flat data (if you are using flat catalog)

magmi doesn't update price index tables

Comment: This has been done many a time, so I would rule this out. Still thumping my head against what could be the issue

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you need to update the indexes and clear cache on completion. I'm sure there's an option in magmi to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin to manage the prices of the entire catalog and it works perfectly! Now I wanted to ask if anyone helps to use something like this to export and then import the "custom options" of the "simple products". Couldn't find anything !! I need to change the fields en masse. Thank you!